# Validate time field for 23:59 format in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, validation, column-validation

I'm trying to add validation to a text column in an SPO list so that entered data only contains values from 00:00 to 23:59. I referred [this article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185947/validate-time-field-in-0000-2359-format-in-sharepoint-2010-list-using-cell-val) for a validation code which works fine. But it does not allow blank values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: From the link you provided, which formula worked for you (which user's answer worked)?  I will extend the same formula & provide you updated formula for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow blank values in column validation, use formula like:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Start Time]), TRUE, <current formula which worked for you goes here>)
```

For Example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Start Time]), TRUE, (LEN([Start Time])=5)+(MID([Start Time],3,1)=":")+(CODE(MID([Start Time],1,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],1,1))<51)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],2,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],2,1))<58)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],4,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],4,1))<54)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],5,1))>47)+(CODE(MID([Start Time],5,1))<58)+IF(CODE(MID([Start Time],1,1))=50, (IF(CODE(MID([Start Time],2,1))>51, 0, 1)), 1)=11)
```

---

**Update from comments**:

I just tried this in my SharePoint site & it allows blank value from list forms as well:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, This works fine when I'm editing or adding new item via grid view. But when I add/ edit an item using new/edit form, it does not allow blank values. Can you please check this scenario?

Comment: I just tried this in my SharePoint site & it allows blank value from list forms as well. See screenshot in my updated answer.

Comment: I tried in an entirely new list copying the same formula. For some reason it works fine in grid view but gives the validation error message for new form.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of new form (with value you passed in form field & validation error) to your original question by editing it?

Comment: Hi, it started working now. I had deleted the list and restored from recycle bin. After some time, new form  started working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad it started working for you.